# How to call each row from a dataframe and plot it, in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, visualization

How can I call each row (ele1, elec2, elec3, elec4) from my dataframe and make a bar plot for each one?
I should end up with 4 bar plots.

```
#This is for the fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns=('F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5'))
df.index='elec' + (df2.index+1).astype(str)
df
```

[image]

```
#This is  my attempt:

for index in df:  
    df1=df.iloc[[index]]
    df1.plot.bar(figsize=(5,1))
```

I should end up with 4 barplots. This is the barplot of row 2 (elec3). But I want for each row.
[image]

Comment: You can transpose and plot.

Comment: the plot that I put is only from the row 2 (elec3). I want a plot for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

First I re-create your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns=('F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5'))
df.index = ['elec1', 'elec2', 'elec3', 'elec4']
```

Next, I create a number of subplots equals to the number of rows in the dataframe.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=df.shape[0])
fig.set_figheight(3)
fig.set_figwidth(9)
```

I then loop through each row of your dataframe, and plot into its corresponding subplot.

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    subset = df.ix[i,:]
    subset.plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[i])
    axes[i].set_title(subset.name)
```

This returns the following output:

[image]

Comment: Hi. I just the empty plots. Please check the EDIT I have just written.

Comment: Hi. It worked. I was executing bad the code. Do you know how to make the bars closer to each one?

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy way to manually decrease the spacing between bars. You could try playing around with the ticks or decreasing the figure size